# Struggling with Copy Constructors in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to write me a copy constructor for my struct but I don't seem to be getting this right and would appreciate any help possible please. I want to do a deep copy, recursively, but I keeping getting suggestions to initialize in the initialization list and that does not seem to be working out well either.

```
struct Node
{
    Node* left; // will be our previous
    Node* right;// will be our next
    Node* previous;// get a handle to the previous node
    string value;

    Node(string nval): left(NULL), right(NULL), previous(NULL), value(nval)
    {

    }

    Node(Node const& node)
     : previous(new Node(node.previous)), 
       left(new Node(node.left)), 
       right(new Node(node.right)), 
       value(node.value)
    {
    }

    Node& operator=(const Node&)
    {
       // ...
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new Node(node.previous)`: `previous` is a pointer, but your `Node` class does not have a constructor that takes a pointer. (The same is true for the others, of course.)

Comment: and what if node.left is NULL? What would you expect `new` to do for you? Don't do this in the initialization list. You have a body for your constructor - do it there.

Comment: And the parenthesis look all wrong.

Comment: @Mat: I fixed that. It seemed to be irrelevant, since he claims runtime errors.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid this recursing infinitely, you need to test for null.  You also need to dereference the objects in the RHS node.

```
 Node(Node const& node) :
     previous(node.previous ? new Node(*node.previous) : NULL),
     left(node.left ? new Node(*node.left) : NULL),
     right(node.right ? new Node(*node.right) : NULL), 
     value(node.value)
 {
 }
```

But this will only work if `previous != next != previous` always holds, and your nodes don't point to each other. If this is a linked list structure, this won't work.

I'm guessing that your nodes do point together, and what you're trying to do here is to clone a whole data structure whenever one node is copied. In that case I can't see a way you can sensibly do this in a copy constructor. I'd suggest making the class noncopyable and writing a separate function to clone the whole data structure. If you provide more context of how your structure of `Node`s is constructed, I may be able to provide a more concrete suggestion.

**Edit**

You indicated in the comments that this is a tree, and that `previous` is the parent node pointer. This copy constructor should do a subtree clone:

```
Node(Node const& node) :
    previous(NULL),
    left(node.left ? new Node(*node.left) : NULL),
    right(node.right ? new Node(*node.right) : NULL), 
    value(node.value)
{
    if (left)
        left->previous = this;
    if (right)
        right->previous = this;
}
```

Note that instead of allocating a new `Node` for `previous`, it leaves it blank and lets its parent set it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You know, this whole incident wouldn't smell so badly if you hadn't said that just _after_ you posted almost exactly the same code (a second after this one).

Comment: I don't get what you mean by if previous !-next !- previous. I am using this for a tree where I keep a pointer to the parent, left and right child nodes. Why would the above not work? What would I need to do in addition to get this to, say copy each node every time it is invoked?

Comment: @Kobojunkie by `previous != next != previous` I mean that those three pointers all point to different objects. If this is a binary tree, is `previous` the parent pointer? if not what is it?